# H2 console is not opening

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I have one maven based springBoot application with embaded in memory H2 database. My application is running on 55000 port. When I am running from SpringBoot I am able to open my H2 console with /H2 mapping but when I am running the jar file from console with command java -Dserver.port=55000 application.jar then when hitting on /H2 path I am getting an Whitelabel page with error

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

My application.properties file is as below,

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.h2.console.path=/H2
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=true 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./applicationDatabase
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=install
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=55000
```

Comment: Please post application.properties

Comment: # H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.h2.console.path=/H2
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=true 
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./applicationDatabase
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=install
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

#create_table_if_not_exists
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=55000

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add application.properties there? Its hardly readable. Also, If possible, please check the logs and see if any error is there. If there is one, please post that also

Comment: One more thing. Did you try /H2 endpoint or /h2-console?

Comment: added my application.properties file. I have added my h2 console path as /H2 so tried with /H2

Comment: There is nothing in the logs, all the other mapping points are working fine

Comment: I copied the same application.properties to my spring boot project and its working fine. Can you please post the error that you were getting?

Comment: Issue is resolved. I just created a fresh project and everything works